# Getting an undefined result in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making my debuts in node.js. So I'm trying to get some data from database to display it into a view. In the model javascript file, I'm trying to make a connection to the database, after that I'm exporting a function to retrieve all the records from the table.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : '',
user     : '',
password : '',
database : ''
});

//Connecting to database.
connection.connect();

 //This a query to get all the records that we will show in the view.
module.exports = {
getAllrecords: function(){
    connection.query('SELECT * from orders', function(err, rows, fields) {
       if (err) throw err;
       var response = JSON.stringify(rows);

       return response;
    });
  }
}
```

In my index layout, I'm trying to display the records, but I'm getting an undefined result.

```
var express  = require('express');
var router   = express.Router();
var database = require('../database');

var records = database.getAllrecords();

console.log(records);
```

So what I'm doing worng ?

Comment: `getAllRecords` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`

Comment: @Quentin are you sure ? `return response;`

Comment: @KubiRoazhon - check carefully to see which function `return response;` is in ... p.s. nailed it

Comment: the connection query function :/ @JaromandaX

Comment: so, not the `getAllRecords` function, right

Comment: @JaromandaX so how cant i export it please.

Comment: use a callback - see the linked question for more information as this question is now marked as a duplicate